# Bootstrap: Image and text alignment?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Goal: Have paragraph of text and image line up and be appropriately sized using Bootstrap. I'm surprised I'm finding this tricky.

I'd like the paragraph to be centered vertically to align with the image. So far if the screen is too large the text is much higher than the image. I'd like it to be centered vertically. Or if the screen is small the image is higher than the text. Can someone advice me how to accomplish this using Bootstrap? Current code & Fiddle below. Thanks for any help!

Check out the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pbm6jkob/)

Here is my code:

```
 <div id='sectionTwo' > 
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id='' class="row">
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <br>
    <p class='text-left aboutUsText' id=''>porchetta alcatra corned beef 
    doner turducken burgdoggen venison prosciutto. Ham brisket leberkas pork 
    chop tenderloin hamburger cow turducken fatback prosciutto. Ham hock 
    burgdoggen bresaola prosciutto ground round. Corned beef venison 
    shoulder tri-tip brisket ham hock ribeye flank bresaola spare ribs 
    meatloaf. Corned beef venison shoulder tri-tip brisket ham hock ribeye 
    flank bresaola spare ribs meatloaf.. </p>
    <br>
    <p class='text-left aboutUsText' id=''> porchetta alcatra corned beef 
    doner turducken burgdoggen venison prosciutto. Ham brisket leberkas pork 
    chop tenderloin hamburger cow turducken fatback prosciutto. Ham hock 
    burgdoggen bresaola prosciutto ground round. Corned beef venison 
    shoulder tri-tip brisket ham hock ribeye flank bresaola spare ribs 
    meatloaf.</p>
    <br>
    </div>

    <div id='imageDiv' class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <br>
    <img  class="img-responsive thumbnail" id='aboutUs' 
    src="https://i.imgur.com/dSbnapT.jpg"> 
<br>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. can you clarify how the items should be positioned? You want the image and text side by side?

Comment: Exactly and vertically aligned so the text is not higher or lower than the image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? [codepen](https://codepen.io/guyogev/pen/jGRpwx?editors=1100)

wrap the paragraphs with a div and use flexbox

```
.text {
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```